# Find sequences in Excel

Tags: excel, sequences

I would like to look into the effects of a sequence of variable X on variable Y. In order to do so, I have to exclude all the rows that, according to the values in column X, don't fit into a particular sequence. For instance, I am interested in the sequence A-B-B. I want to go from here

```
Variable X   Variable Y
A            2
B            7
B            5
A            12
B            9
A            8
```

To here

```
Variable X   Variable Y
A            2
B            7
B            5
```

Please note that I don't need to rewrite the column necessarily, but I surely need to get rid of anything that is not part of the sequence ABB. 
Thank you for your answers

Comment: As SO is not a code writing service, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @pnuts yes I agree. Only reason I ask for what OP has tried is because firstly I think you learn a lot more if you first try out things (even if it fails, you potentially can learn something new). Second, I think OP will appreciate the provided answer lot more if they have made an attempt rather than just coming here and getting there answers. But I guess we are not hear to teach but help :)

Comment: If there is more than one triplet, do you want only the first triplet or all of them??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I would like all of them

Comment: @Zac I've tried IF formulas such as (on C5) 
=IF(I5="A";IF(AND(I6="B";I7="B");1;0);IF(AND(I6="A";I7="A");1;0))                The problem with this is that it captures also cells that are not in the sequence, and anyway I would have a 1 only aside the first cell of the sequence. I have also tried with MATCH function but it didn't work out at all (I get "VALUE")

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED. Assuming `Variable X` is in A1, Please try adding a couple of blank rows at the top and a couple `z`s in the first two empty cells below A3 in ColumnA then in C3 and copied down to suit:

```
=OR(AND(A1="A",A2="B",A3="B"),AND(A2="A",A3="B",A4="B"),AND(A3="A",A4="B",A5="B"),LEFT(A3)=LEFT(B3))
```

Then filter on ColumnC to deselect TRUE and delete those rows.